# i18n добавление динамического текста через jsx тег

Tags: reactjs, i18n

Есть простой jsx код.

```
<Typography>
   {`${t('txt.title',  { phone } )}`}
</Typography>
```

И его перевод в соответственном json файле.

```
"txt": {
      "title": "На номер {{ phone }} был отправлен код верификации.",
 }
```

Текст выводиться все норм. Но как мне добиться результата чтобы выводимый текст был обернут в какой-то тег. К примеру тег `<b></b>`

Попробовал написать так:

```
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next';

<Trans t={t('txt.title')}><b>{phone}</b></Trans>
```

Не помогло.

Comment: Не пробовали добавить тег непосредственно к переменной `phone`? `\`<b>${phone}</b>\`` и этот же результат подставить в перевод?

Comment: @MoloF пробовал, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать `Trans` компонент следующим образом

```
import React from "react";
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next, useTranslation, Trans } from "react-i18next";
import "./styles.css";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      "Welcome to React": "Welcome to React and react-i18next",
      title: "На номер <1>{{phone}}</1> был отправлен код верификации."
    }
  }
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en",

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

export default function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const phone = "732434249";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{t("Welcome to React")}</h1>
      <Trans i18nKey="title" phone={phone}>
        На номер <b>{{ phone }}</b> был отправлен код верификации.
      </Trans>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- Интерактивный пример также доступен на [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wildflower-ingez?file=/src/App.js:0-1175)
- Подробнее можно почитать в документации react-i18next по [ссылке](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-with-react-components)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.